# Android : how to divide JSON into two parts

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout

i have json as below :

```
    {
    "pp": {
        "status_marital_pmg": "BELUM MENIKAH",
        "nama_pmg": "tomy",
        "kerjab_pmg": "-",
        "pendidikan_pmg": "S1",
        "agama_pmg": "KRISTENKATOLIK",
        "bidang_industri_pmg": "JASAKEUANGAN",
        "warga_pmg": "-",
        "hubungan_pmg_ttg": "DiriSendiri",
        "pendanaana_pmg": "GAJI",
        "pendanaan_pmg": "GAJI",
        "usia_pmg": 33,
        "penghasilan_pmg": "-",
        "kelamin_pmg": "Pria",
        "tujuan_pmg": "INVESTASI",
        "tujuana_pmg": "INVESTASI",
        "kerja_pmg": "KARYAWAN",
        "bidang_industria_pmg": "JASAKEUANGAN"
    }
}
```

i want to divide and save my json into two parts, they are : listPP and listPPL and in my layout, i want to divide it into two parts first part for listPP and other part for listPPL, but when i run it, there is just one part: ListPPL and it show in first part of layout, not second part of layout.
ListPP doesn't show anything, this is my code :

```
try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            PPVariabel varpp = null;
            PPPelengkapvariabel varppl=null;
            JSONObject pp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("pp");
            {
            for (int i=0; i<PP.length;i++){
            varpp= new PPVariabel(pp.optString("nama_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("kerjab_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("warga_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("usia_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("status_marital_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("kelamin_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("agama_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("pendidikan_pmg"));
            listPP.add(varpp);

            LinearLayout linear1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pp1);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            setListAdapter(new PPViewerAdapter(this, listPP,PP));
            }
            for (int j=0; j<Pelengkap.length;j++){
            varppl= new PPPelengkapvariabel (pp.optString("tujuan_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("tujuana_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("penghasilan_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("pendanaan_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("pendanaana_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("kerja_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("bidang_industri_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("bidang_industria_pmg"),
                    pp.optString("hubungan_pmg_ttg"));
                listPPL.add(varppl);

                LinearLayout linear2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dpl2);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ppl);
                setListAdapter(new PPDataPelengkapAdapter(this, listPPL,Pelengkap));
            }
```

this is my layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/medium_gray">
     <ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true" 
    android:fadingEdgeLength="1dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">


 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pp1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="DATA DIRI"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:typeface="sans"/>

       <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="470dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dpl2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="DATA PELENGKAP"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:typeface="sans"/>

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ppl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="1000dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"/>
       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

is there any wrong with my code? if yes, is there anyone can help me to solve my problem? thank you

Comment: If you want to divide your JSON in two parts then you need to add the two separate array for your JSON response in which one array contains the details of ListPP and another contains the ListPPL inside the PP arraylist.